# How to provide relative URL in bat file in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I am using the below code to access and run a bat file

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p =null;
p = runtime.exec("cmd /c c:/{foldername}/codereview.bat");
```

I realized that my code is not portable as i have hardcoded the path, so i copied my bat file in a folder under /src and am now trying to use it after removing the c:/{foldername} part but 
the code is not working for me... The file can not be found.

Please help as to how i can provide the relative path inside the bat file.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your exact problem but I think this may help you:

To get the absolute path of your source program(the `class` file executing) use this:

> String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Now you can dynamically the path of your program and the hence the `batch` file(which I think is relative to the `class` file)